# Returning results based on last date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm interested in retaining only individuals in a Microsoft SQL Server query that have a value over a certain threshold on two separate dates. If the individuals have a score higher than 150 twice, I would like to return their ID, the second date that their score was above 150, and the score on the second date.

Here is the data:

```
SubjectID   DATE         Score
001         01/11/2014   147
001         02/11/2013   151
002         02/10/2015   152
003         08/12/2013   155
002         01/31/2012   159
003         07/19/2016   157
```

So I for the results, I would like to return the following:

```
SubjectID   DATE         Score
002         02/10/2015   152
003         07/19/2016   157
```

Comment: What if there are three dates?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified. Just want the second date.

Comment: So even if someone took the test of 5 different days with all 5 days scored over 150, you only want the second day's score, ignoring the 3 tests taken afterwards?

Comment: Is it possible for someone to take the test twice in one day?

Comment: So far I would just be looking for the second test where the value of score crosses the 150 threshold for the second time. There would only be one test per day. If someone took the test 5 different days with all 5 days scored over 150, we would only be interested in the second date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want anything beyond the first, then one method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.score > 150 and
      t.date > (select min(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.subjectId = t.subjectId and t2.score > 150)
```

If you want only the maximum such date:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.score > 150 and
      t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.subjectId = t.subjectId and t2.score > 150)
```

Comment: If the table name was Clinic, would t = Clinic and t2 = Clinic2? I'm getting an error for when I enter Clinic2

Comment: @statsguyz The subquery is `SELECT`ing from `t` and aliasing that as `t2`.

Comment: Gordon, how does the subquery perform vs window functions? I know that subqueries can sometimes increase the performance of the overall query, but I thought an aggregate would result in a RBAR operation. Though I guess this isn't really aggregating anything from the original table, so I may just be thinking too hard about this. I'm curious, and your opinion is definitely one I listen to.

Comment: @Shawn . . . You have to test on your own data.  Sometimes, the performance on the subquery is much better than using the window functions.  This has to do with the optimization -- the window function has to assign the value to each row and return it for further processing.  The subquery may just be able to do an index lookup for each row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I kinda suspected it would be an "It Depends" answer. Because it usually does. I have your book, so I know you're pretty well informed about query performance. :-)  I was hoping you had a magic bullet. I have usually been leery of sub-queries, because they are very easy to destroy performance with, but if done right they can perform a good bit better with good indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rank..Over

```
select * from 
(
   select *, RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY SubjectID ORDER BY [Date]) Rnk
   from [YourTable]
   where Score > 150
) x
where Rnk = 2
```

Comment: If it's possible to take multiple tests in a day, `RANK()` may result in no record with a `2`. `DENSE_RANK()` may be better, but that can make for multiple `2` records. So it really depends on OP's needs.  :-S

Answer (score 1):

for id alone

```
SELECT a.subjectId
FROM Clinic a
WHERE a.score > 150 
      AND a.date IN (SELECT MAX(b.date) 
                     FROM Clinic b 
                     WHERE b.subjectId = a.subjectId 
                            AND b.score > 150)
```

for all fields

```
 SELECT *
    FROM Clinic a
    WHERE a.score > 150 
          AND a.date IN (SELECT MAX(b.date) 
                         FROM Clinic b 
                         WHERE b.subjectId = a.subjectId 
                                AND b.score > 150)
```

Comment: If I wanted to search specifically for math tests in a column called 'SUBJECT' could I just add the following between WHERE and a.score: a.SUBJECT LIKE 'Math' AND ?

Comment: Yes. It depends on how 'Math' is specified in your table. if mentioned as maths then  use 'maths' . Use the exact string.

Answer (score -1):

```
select sub.* 
FROM( 
    Select t.subjectId,
         t.date,
         t.score,
        , COUNT(t.score) OVER (PARTITION BY t.subjectId) as date_count
        , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY t.subjectId ORDER BY t.date desc ) as latest_date_rank
    FROM  tbl t 
    WHERE t.score >150 
) as sub 
WHERE sub.date_count >= 2 AND sub.latest_date_rank =1
```

I hope this will work for n no of records and will give latest dates record. Plz ignore formating as typed from handheld device.